# Exclude category to "the_breadcrumb" functions

Tags: categories

(sorry for my english) in my theme I Breadcrumbs function. I would like to exclude the categories, can you help me? here's the code:

```
    function the_breadcrumb() {
    global $post;
if (!is_home()) {
    echo '<a href="'.get_option('home').'">'.home.'</a>';
    if (is_category()) {
        echo " / ";
        echo single_cat_title();
    } elseif(is_single() && !is_attachment()) {
        $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0];
        echo " / ";
        echo get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' ');
        echo " / ";
        echo the_title_shorten(45,'...');
    }       
    elseif (is_search()) {
        echo " / " . cerca;
    }       
    elseif (is_page() && $post->post_parent) {
        echo ' / <a href="'.get_permalink($post->post_parent).'">';
        echo get_the_title($post->post_parent);
        echo "</a> / ";
        echo the_title_shorten(45,'...');       
    }
    elseif (is_page() OR is_attachment()) {
        echo " / "; 
        echo the_title_shorten(45,'...');
    }
    elseif (is_author()) {
        echo wp_title(' / Profilo');
        echo "";
    }
    elseif (is_404()) {
        echo " / "; 
        echo errore_404;
    }       
    elseif (is_archive()) {
        echo wp_title(' / ');       
    }
        }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [get_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories). It supports an exclude argument.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
if (is_category()) {
    echo " / ";
    echo single_cat_title();
} elseif(is_single() && !is_attachment()) {
```

to this

```
if(is_single() && !is_attachment()) {
```

Comment: Thanks Rarst of the answer, but I meant a specific category (eg, 3 or 4) .....

Comment: @Fask then I am not sure, could you please clarify that? What exactly you want or don't want to happen under which conditions?

Comment: hello I would like to exclude categories 3 and 4 from get_category_parents

Comment: @Fask that function doesn't support any arguments to exclude stuff and is recursive on top... It might be easier to modify result with `str_replace()` or something.

Comment: the fact is I'm not an expert you can help me?

Comment: @Fask could you please update your question to be more clear and focused? You ask one thing in title, different in comments and there seems to be too much code that is not relevant.